# R: if statement nested in a for loop doesn't work

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to turn time from 21:00 to 2:00 am into a continuous variable.  The only times I have fall during this period.  I am adding 24 to times after midnight.  The object Call.LIBL.12 is data for call surveys for particular frog  species in 2012.

This code works:

```
if (Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[6] < 10) {
    Call.LIBL.12$Hour3[6] <- Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[6]+24
} else {
    Call.LIBL.12$Hour3[6] <- Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[6]
}
```

Nested in a for loop to do it for all 82 sites does not work:

```
for (i in 1:82) {
    if (Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[i] < 10) {
        Call.LIBL.12$Hour3[i] <- Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[i]+24
    } else {
        Call.LIBL.12$Hour3[i] <- Call.LIBL.12$Hour2[i]
    }
}
```

Seems like simple problem.  Yet I can't figure out why it won't work.

TIA

Comment: have you tried using `ifelse`? what is the error you get? does `Call.LIBL.12$Hour3` exist before this for loop?

Comment: It will aslo help if you make your question reproducible, either by recreating it as a minimal example or posting a link to the actual data. Based on your description it is hard for me to figure out how exactly your data is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifelse()`, not `if ... else`.